# Collection<Collection<Person>> to Collection<Person> in one linq statment

Tags: c#, .net, linq

i have `List<List<Person>>` i want it  to copy all people in the previous collection to `List<Person>` collection.

i did it like:

```
        var People = new List<List<Person>>{ new List<Person>{...},...  };
        var people = new List<Person>();
        People.ForEach(q => people.AddRange(q.People));
        return people;
```

is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Little suggestion.. If you check this code with fXCop it will give warning. You should not link one collection in another. Do create separate class to achieve what you want

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var allPersons = People.SelectMany(p => p);
```

Answer (score 8):

You should use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) extension method for that:

```
var people = People.SelectMany(p => p)
```